# Extraction of the sentence of a file based on the Stanford Open IE triplet in the form of Json

Tags: json, python-3.x, stanford-nlp

I am trying to extract a sentence from a file based on the Stannford OpenIE triplet. I have it in the form of json file.

```
"openie": [
    {
      "subject": "We",
      "subjectSpan": [0, 1],
      "relation": "drive back to",
      "relationSpan": [3, 6],
      "object": "Missouri night",
      "objectSpan": [6, 10]
    },
    {
      "subject": "We",
      "subjectSpan": [0, 1],
      "relation": "drive back to",
      "relationSpan": [3, 6],
      "object": "Missouri",
      "objectSpan": [6, 7]
    },
    {
      "subject": "We",
      "subjectSpan": [0, 1],
      "relation": "decided",
      "relationSpan": [1, 2],
      "object": "drive back to Missouri night",
      "objectSpan": [3, 10]
    },
    {
      "subject": "We",
      "subjectSpan": [0, 1],
      "relation": "drive back to",
      "relationSpan": [3, 6],
      "object": "Missouri same night",
      "objectSpan": [6, 10]
    },
    {
      "subject": "We",
      "subjectSpan": [0, 1],
      "relation": "drive to",
      "relationSpan": [3, 6],
      "object": "Missouri",
      "objectSpan": [6, 7]
    },
    {
      "subject": "We",
      "subjectSpan": [0, 1],
      "relation": "decided",
      "relationSpan": [1, 2],
      "object": "drive to Missouri",
      "objectSpan": [3, 7]
    },
    {
      "subject": "We",
      "subjectSpan": [0, 1],
      "relation": "decided",
      "relationSpan": [1, 2],
      "object": "drive back to Missouri",
      "objectSpan": [3, 7]
    },
    {
      "subject": "We",
      "subjectSpan": [0, 1],
      "relation": "decided",
      "relationSpan": [1, 2],
      "object": "drive to Missouri same night",
      "objectSpan": [3, 10]
    },
    {
      "subject": "We",
      "subjectSpan": [0, 1],
      "relation": "drive to",
      "relationSpan": [3, 6],
      "object": "Missouri same night",
      "objectSpan": [6, 10]
    },
    {
      "subject": "We",
      "subjectSpan": [0, 1],
      "relation": "decided",
      "relationSpan": [1, 2],
      "object": "drive to Missouri night",
      "objectSpan": [3, 10]
    },
    {
      "subject": "We",
      "subjectSpan": [0, 1],
      "relation": "decided",
      "relationSpan": [1, 2],
      "object": "drive",
      "objectSpan": [3, 4]
    },
    {
      "subject": "We",
      "subjectSpan": [0, 1],
      "relation": "decided",
      "relationSpan": [1, 2],
      "object": "drive back to Missouri same night",
      "objectSpan": [3, 10]
    },
    {
      "subject": "We",
      "subjectSpan": [0, 1],
      "relation": "decided",
      "relationSpan": [1, 2],
      "object": "drive back",
      "objectSpan": [3, 5]
    },
    {
      "subject": "Missouri",
      "subjectSpan": [6, 7],
      "relation": "is  at_time",
      "relationSpan": [9, 10],
      "object": "night",
      "objectSpan": [9, 10]
    },
    {
      "subject": "We",
      "subjectSpan": [0, 1],
      "relation": "drive to",
      "relationSpan": [3, 6],
      "object": "Missouri night",
      "objectSpan": [6, 10]
    }
  ],
```

I need to extract this specific sentence from the text file from which this json was extracted. 
I am trying to do a text summarization.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is not enough information in this structure to resolve the original sentence.  Specifically, one instance of `to`, and the `the` are both missing, and would have to be inferred.

Comment: Is this from the CoreNLP output? Shouldn't the `openie` list be attached to a sentence JSON? If you're calling from the command line: the Reverb output format is the most verbose, including within it the text of the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Stanford CoreNLP output attaches the `openie` output to each sentence.

For instance if you loaded the json into Python you might get this:

`sample_json['sentences'][0]['openie']`

You can access info about the sentence from that json.

For instance:

`sample_json['sentences'][0]['tokens']`